# Rails using kickstarter rack-attack IP blacklisting with Cloudflare

Tags: ip-address, cloudflare, rackattack

Rails app, using Kickstarter's [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack)

Within my config/rack-attack.rb file, I have:

```
class Rack::Attack
  Rack::Attack.blacklist ('block ip') do |req|
    # Request are blocked if the return value is truthy
    '68.888.23.22' == req.ip
    # req.ip if IPCat.datacenter?(req.ip)
  end
end
```

This worked fine until I started using CloudFlare.  The req.ip is now a Cloudflare IP vs that actual end user's IP

I had a similar issue when trying to save the user's IP to my server logs (was saving the Cloudflare IPs). In order to fix this, I added the following to my application controller:

```
module ActionDispatch
  class Request < Rack::Request
    alias :remote_ip_orig :remote_ip
    def remote_ip
      @remote_ip ||= (@env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] || remote_ip_orig)
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a similar process in order to use the HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP as the req.ip within rack-attack?

Comment: find a solution here?

Comment: I did not.  Ended up just manually blacklisting IPs within the Cloudflare settings.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add:

```
class Rack::Attack::Request < ::Rack::Request
  def cf_ip
    @env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] ? @env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] : ip
  end
end
```

Then you can use:

```
throttle('req/ip', :limit => 300, :period => 5.minutes) do |req|
  req.cf_ip
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve the problem on both **ActionPack** and the **Rack::Attack::Request** you can do this:

```
module ActionPack
  module Cloudflare
    module Request

      def remote_ip
        remote_ip_cloudflare || super
      end

      private

      def remote_ip_cloudflare
        @env['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']
      end

    end
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Request.class_eval do
  prepend ActionPack::Cloudflare::Request
end

Rack::Attack::Request.class_eval do
  prepend ActionPack::Cloudflare::Request
end
```

I hope it helps.